# Permission error on Gitlab CI deployment with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gitlab, google-app-engine-python

I try to make a full process of integrated deployment with Gitlab and Google AppEngine.

But the deployment fail because it seems I miss rights. I really don't know which right is needed here.

I activated the App Engine API and the Cloud Build API.

The rights my service has:

[image: The rights my service has]

my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
Staging Deployment:
  stage: Deploy
  environment:
    name: Staging
  before_script:
    - echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-jessie main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
    - curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -qq -y install google-cloud-sdk
  script:
    - echo $DEPLOY_KEY_FILE_PRODUCTION > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud config list
    - gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION
    - gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION app deploy gae/test.yml
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

And finally my test.yml:

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37
service: testing
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT manta.wsgi --timeout 120
default_expiration: "5m"
env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: manta.settings.dev
handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
  # static directory.
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static/
  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app.
  # It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted
  # (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static
  # files defined.
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
# [END django_app]
```

And the error I have during deployment:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps/testing]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that you have permission to view applications on the project.
```

Comment: Adding the `--log-http --verbosity=debug` flags to the `gcloud app deploy` command might show addicional information of what is causing the error. Also make sure you are using the correct Project ID.

Comment: @Tartempion34 Did you find a solution? I have the same problem